# How to stream video from an IP camera using PyQt5 QtMultimedia?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, webcam, qtmultimedia

The task is to stream an image from 5 IP cameras using QtMultimedia from the PyQt5 framework. Initially I tried to use OpenCV, but the parallel broadcast of 5 video streams reduced fps. We decided to try QtMultimedia in an attempt to improve performance.

To begin with, I tried to connect to 1-2 cameras and further scale this solution. Camera Name: D-Link DCS-931L. I connect the camera to the network via tp-link.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class DualCameraApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Dual Camera App')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.camera1 = QCamera(QCameraInfo.defaultCamera())
        #self.camera2 = QCamera(QCameraInfo.availableCameras()[1])

        self.viewfinder1 = QCameraViewfinder()
        #self.viewfinder2 = QCameraViewfinder()

        self.camera1.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder1)
        #self.camera2.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder2)

        self.camera1.start()
        #self.camera2.start()


        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewfinder1)
        #layout.addWidget(self.viewfinder2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DualCameraApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I use the Camera class to work with cameras. I use the QCameraInfo class to connect the camera. It has the defaultCamera() and available Cameras() methods. The first method gives the default system camera, and the second gives a list of cameras in the system.

**Problem**: These methods do not allow access to IP cameras. In total, I can only connect to my camera in my laptop.

Then I was able to get a link to the video stream and tried to connect using the link.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QCamera
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class VideoPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("IP Camera Video Stream")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(video_widget)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(self, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(video_widget)

        # http://IP/h264.flv - with sound?
        url = "http://admin:admin1@192.168.1.141/video.cgi"
        self.media_content = QMediaContent(QUrl(url))
        self.media_player.setMedia(self.media_content)
        self.media_player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it is also not successful. At the output, I get an empty window with no video stream.

Please help me figure it out.

Update:

my attempt to rewrite the code in PyQt6

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl


class VideoPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("IP Camera Video Stream")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(video_widget)

        self.container = QWidget()
        self.container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)

        url = "rtsp://admin:admin1@192.168.1.157/play1.sdp"
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.media_player.setSource(QUrl(url))
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)
        # self.video_widget.show()
        self.media_player.play()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: QCamera will never work with an IP camera, as the [documentation explicitly says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html) that it's intended for *system camera devices*. Your media player instance is most certainly garbage collected, as you're not setting any parent nor make it persistent; change to `self.media_player = ...` (or at least use `self` instead of `None` as first argument in the constructor). You'll probably need to do that for the QMediaContent too.

Comment: @musicamante thanks. I tried your advice. I added `self.` to `media_player` and `media_content`, but it didn't help. Code in the post is edited. by the way, the LED on the camera starts blinking when I run the code

Comment: That's a start. Now, it could be a problem with playback capabilities: in Qt5, the QtMultimedia module always relied on the multimedia backend of the OS (since Qt 6.6 an internal ffmpeg build is used by default): your system may just not be able to decode the video. Start by running your program in a terminal/prompt and see if it prints some useful output (which is always a good thing to test your programs, even if they work); you probably need to install third-party codecs; on Windows, search "K-Lite"; on Linux, check the package manager for additional gstreamer codecs; on macOS, don't know.

Comment: @musicamante I don't think this could be a problem with playback capabilities. OpenCV perfectly reproduces the image from the cameras.

Comment: The fact that OpenCv is able to show the camera stream is completely irrelevant, OpenCV is not Qt, nor it uses the system codecs. Please follow the suggestions above.

Comment: @musicamante I have installed the "K-Lite" codecs in Windows. It didn't help. An empty window also opens. Moreover, I tried to rewrite the code in PyQt6 (see the update to the post). It didn't work out. In the window that opens, there is just a black screen, instead of a picture with a camera. I checked the camera's performance, the video stream is running in VLC-player

Comment: I've also had this same question in the past. Was trying to pipe Cam > Mediapipe > OpenCV. It's a shame Qt doesn't make the solution obvious

Comment: @Cyril Did you try to run the program in a terminal/prompt as asked above? Do you get any warning or debug info? Also, test QMediaPlayer with some other *physical* standard video files, so that you can at least understand if playback *does* work.

Comment: @9Guy OpenCV is not part of Qt, how could it make something like that "obvious"?!

Comment: @musicamante PIL isn't part of Qt, yet it makes the solution obvious for displaying a PIL image in Qt. OpenCV is a hugely popular library, and yet

Comment: @9Guy It's not Qt that makes it "obvious", it's just that the way PIL objects are made make it sometimes easier. And it's actually not that different than OpenCV: one only has to be aware of how image formats work, which is *not* always obvious and often underestimated: most of the times, OpenCV>Qt conversion issues are caused by people that know anything about the image formats they're using and expect things to magically work out. In any case, all this is irrelevant: the OP was perfectly able to use OpenCV, they wanted to try a different method because of performance issues.

Comment: @musicamante I tried to run it from the command line. When running, the PyQt5 version displays the message in command promt: "DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80040216 (IDispatch error #22)". The PyQt6 version does not output anything to the command promt, it just opens a window with a black background. I also did a simple video player that just plays video files. The video is playing successfully. I don't know what to do

Comment: @Cyril The first may be caused by the inability to use the rtsp protocol (but I'm not completely sure). For the second, I sincerely don't know. I remember that in some previous versions there were problems with QVideoWidget not being able to properly resize its contents under certain conditions. Consider trying the QGraphicsVideoWidget within a QGraphicsView. Unfortunately I don't use Windows, nor I can test your specific case. See if the camera provides other protocols/media formats and check them if possible.

Comment: @musicamante When you advised me to "See if the camera supports other protocols/media formats, and check them if possible." I decided to try connecting two other cameras and one of them worked. Foolishly, I did not think to launch other cameras after making changes according to your first recommendations.
However, the stream does not work faster than OpenCV, even a little slower. Can you tell me how to set up a video stream using QtMultimedia, for example, to remove caching?